# Java EE  (struts/hibernate): Want to change main menu based on login, should use sitemesh in this case or is there any other option?

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, sitemesh

I am making an application based on `struts and hibernate` , where based on user logins I have categorized different home screens for different users.

i.e.

Doctor logs in : DoctorHomePage.jsp

Nurse logs in : NurseHomePage.jsp

.

.

.

But I want to avoid this and make a single Home page and load **various main menus** and **extruders** , based on login credentials. Should I use **sitemesh** for this or is there a better solution then this. Just heard about sitemesh.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest you to use [Spring security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/) for such use-case.Based on the logged in user, you can assign different role to the user like Doctor or Nurse and can show the menu items as per the user role.

This will help you much in future enhancement and its easy to add more roles in future and Spring security can easily handle all of this for you.

Alternatively you can keep your existing work approach to make pages based on the user role and included them based on the person who has logged in and what role/permissions logged in user have.

Comment: Could it work with struts framework as I am not using spring in the project.

Comment: well Struts2 do not have any role based system,but if you want to do than you can do a little tweak like when user logged in create a field namely ROLE in the user bean and assign its a values based on that you can show the menu applicable to the user in command

Comment: +1 for your answer , but I would like to know if I can integrate this spring security mechanism with my framework only to allow the ROLE based logins if yes then please tell me how and if not then how come a bean would help to dynamically detect a different menu are you talking about `sitemesh` way out.

Comment: with Spring you have different security tags and you can show certain menu items based on the role assigned to user,all you need to tell Spring which menu to show to which user with what role.I am not very familiar with `sitemesh`,what i am talking is like you can create a file in your user bean say ROLE and base don this value can show menu,but in that case you need to put a lot of conditions or you can create blocks and based on ROLE value you can show those blcoks,IMO i will go wit Spring which is more flexible and powerful